# Matrix Function Minimization

Tags: matlab

I have a function A = X + W .* Y where all of the variables are (M x N) matrices.

I want to minimize sqr(A) over W such that the elements of W follow the equation: 
W(m,n) = W(m,n-1) + 0.5

I was studying matlab default functions like fminsearch or fmincon, but couldn't actually relate to what I want.

If anybody can please show me the direction.

Thanks

Comment: When you say minimize `A` over `W`, do you mean minimize the norm of `A`?

Comment: Oh sorry ... missed that part .. I am supposed to minimize (A)^2 (first bracket, not |.|) .. Now this is another confusion .. How can I minimize a matrix, not it's norm? May be it was meant to minimize 2-norm.

Comment: I'd assume it's the 2-norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
M = 7;
N = 4;
X = rand(M,N);
Y = rand(M,N);

% This makes a matrix that follows your rule for W, because there are only M unique elements with the rule.
W =@(x,n) repmat(x(:), 1, n) + repmat(0:0.5:0.5*(n-1), numel(x), 1);
A =@(x,n) X + W(x,n) .* Y;

y = fminsearch(@(y) norm(A(y, N)), rand(M, 1))
w = W(y, N)
a = A(y, N)
```

Comment: hi .. seems it's working very nice. just one confusion. The output y is a Mx1 (e.g. 7x1 in this case). So does that mean it's minimizing the 2-norm of each row of A individually?

Comment: I don't beloved so, but I don't work with minimization functions very frequently.

Comment: I have accepted the answer, it is correct theoretically. However, the function hanged the software for M,N in the range of 400-500. I'll try to build up some optimized way on your code.